# Align text center in the merged region in excel using apache poi in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have created an excel sheet, where I am inserting the value to cell and merging cells vertically at the same time and I am able to achieve that but the problem is that, I am not able to align text vertically center in the merged cell.Currently, text is showing at the bottom of vertically merged cell.

here's my code,

```
    CellStyle cs = null;
    cs = wb.createCellStyle();
    cs.setWrapText(true);
    //cs.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cs.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
    cs.setFont(f);



            Row row[]=new Row[pageListAcrToDept.size()]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < pageListAcrToDept.size(); i++) {
                rowIndex = 8 + i ;
                row[i]=sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
            }

            List<List<String>> datas=new ArrayList<>();
            datas.add(pageListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(notesListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(treatmentListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(upcListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(itemCodeListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(descListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(subDeptListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(limitListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(XforListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(priceListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(couponListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(adzoneListAcrToDept);
            datas.add(promoDescListAcrToDept);

            for (int column = 0; column < 13; column++) {
                List <String> list=datas.get(column);
            int index=0;
            for (int i = 0, prev = -1; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (i == list.size() - 1 || ! list.get(i).equals(list.get(i + 1))) {
                    //System.out.printf("number: %d, count: %d%n", list.get(i), i - prev);


                    for(int pos=0;pos<i - prev;pos++){
                        int posi=index+pos;
                    Cell cell=  row[posi].createCell(column);
                    cell.setCellStyle((CellStyle) cs);
                    cell.setCellValue(list.get(i));
                    }
                    int startrowpos=index+8;
                    int endrowpos=index+8+(i - prev)-1;
                    if(startrowpos==endrowpos){
                        LOG.info("don't merge");
                    }else{
                    CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(startrowpos, endrowpos,
                            column, column);
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);
                    }
                    index=index+(i - prev);
                    prev = i;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This question shows exemplary why a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is necessary. In actual `apache poi` version (3.15)  the vertical alignment works in general also with merged regions. So why it does not work in your special case? Nobody else except you can know it, since your example code is not complete and verifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolved this problem. I am posting here the changes,because it may help other.

```
     for (int column = 0; column < 13; column++) {
                List <String> list=datas.get(column);
            int index=0;
            for (int i = 0, prev = -1; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (i == list.size() - 1 || ! list.get(i).equals(list.get(i + 1))) {
                    //System.out.printf("number: %d, count: %d%n", list.get(i), i - prev);

                    int posi=0;
                    for(int pos=0;pos<i - prev;pos++){
                        if(pos==0){
                            posi=index+pos;
                        }
                    }
                    int startrowpos=index+8;
                    int endrowpos=index+8+(i - prev)-1;
                    if(startrowpos==endrowpos){
                        LOG.info("don't merge");
                        Cell cell=  row[posi].createCell(column);
                        cell.setCellStyle((CellStyle) cs);
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i));
                    }else{
                    CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(startrowpos, endrowpos,
                            column, column);
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(cellRangeAddress);
                        Cell cell=  row[posi].createCell(column);
                        cell.setCellStyle((CellStyle) cs);
                        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i));
                    }
                    index=index+(i - prev);
                    prev = i;
                }
            }
        }
```